# MAUI DevExpress - Issues with using DXStackLayout

Tags: devexpress, maui, .net-8.0

I am currently new to MAUI and DevExpress and have run into an issue with using the DXStackLayout layout. Here is my XAML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MVVMTestMaui.MainPage"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:MVVMTestMaui.Model.Responses"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:MVVMTestMaui.ViewModel"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:LoginViewModel"
             xmlns:dxco="clr-namespace:DevExpress.Maui.Controls;assembly=DevExpress.Maui.Controls"
             xmlns:dx="clr-namespace:DevExpress.Maui.Core;assembly=DevExpress.Maui.Core"
             Title="{Binding Title}">

    <ScrollView>
        <dx:DXStackLayout>
            <Switch x:Name="switch" IsToggled="True" HorizontalOptions="Start" />
            <dxco:ShimmerView IsLoading="{Binding Source={x:Reference switch}, Path=IsToggled, Mode=TwoWay}" HeightRequest="50" WaveDuration="00:00:02.00">
                <Label Text="Loading..." />
            </dxco:ShimmerView>
            <Label
                Text="My first task app"
                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                FontSize="25"
            />
            <Label
                Text="Username:"
                FontSize="12"
            />
            <Entry
                Text="{Binding Username}"
                Margin="0, -25, 0, 0"
            />
            <Label
                Text="Password:"
                FontSize="12"
            />
            <Entry
                Text="{Binding Password}"
                Margin="0, -25, 0, 0"
            />
            <Button
                Text="Login"
                Command="{Binding LoginCommand}"
                Margin="0, 20, 0, 0"
            />
            <Label
                Text="{Binding IsLoggedIn}"
            />
        </dx:DXStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

My `MauiProgram.cs`:

```
using DevExpress.Maui;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using MVVMTestMaui.Services;
using MVVMTestMaui.ViewModel;

namespace MVVMTestMaui
{
    public static class MauiProgram
    {
        public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
        {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                .UseDevExpress()
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
                .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                {
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
                });

            //Views dependancy injection
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainPage>();

            //ViewModel dependancy injection
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<LoginViewModel>();

            //Service dependancy injection
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<LoginService>();
#if DEBUG
            builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif

            return builder.Build();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error I get:

`The type or namespace name 'DevExpress' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

`The type 'dx:DXStackLayout' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.`

`'MauiAppBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseDevExpress' and no accessible extension method 'UseDevExpress' accepting a first argument of type 'MauiAppBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

`Cannot resolve type "clr-namespace:DevExpress.Maui.Core;assembly=DevExpress.Maui.Core:dx:DXStackLayout".`

If I replace `dx:DXStackLayout` with `VerticalStackLayout` the errors disappear and the app compiles. Could this be an issue with the xaml namespace I am using?

I have tried following [this](https://docs.devexpress.com/MAUI/404602/layouts/layouts?v=23.2) tutorial on DevExpress layouts. I would expect the code from the above tutorial to run, but have received an error.

Comment: Install (or reinstall) the relevant DevExpress nuget packages

Comment: @Jason I've tried uninstalling the `DevExpress.Maui.CollectionView` and I get `Package with id "DevExpress.Maui.CollectionView" does not exist`. Same with all other DevExpress packages

Comment: https://docs.devexpress.com/GeneralInformation/115912/installation/install-devexpress-controls-using-nuget-packages

Comment: Please make sure that you properly configured the DevExpress NuGet feed: [Get Started with DevExpress Controls for .NET Multi-platform App UI (.NET MAUI)](https://docs.devexpress.com/MAUI/403249/get-started/get-started)

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution? I tried the steps above and still get the same error

Comment: @OverMars I haven't found a solution for it unfortunately